# When calling FSCTL_GET_RETRIEVAL_POINTERS and the vcn gets rounded down, can this happen when asking for the first extent?

Tags: windows

The documentation for
STARTING_VCN_INPUT_BUFFER 
says: The VCN at which the operation will begin enumerating extents in the file. This value may be rounded down to the first VCN of the extent in which the specified extent is found.

I can understand why asking for cluster #1 will get you cluster #0 but since it doesn't say anything to this effect, is it possible that if you ask for cluster #0 you'll get something else?

My concern is that my program is skipping the blocks of data that this function returns and if it rounds down I might be skipping something important that I don't want to miss.

Comment: of course when input `StartingVcn` is 0 - output `StartingVcn` (in `RETRIEVAL_POINTERS_BUFFER`) also will 0

Comment: ignore `RETRIEVAL_POINTERS_BUFFER.StartingVcn` you can not - this is error in general case. because all information in `RETRIEVAL_POINTERS_BUFFER` exactly based on `RETRIEVAL_POINTERS_BUFFER.StartingVcn` but not on `STARTING_VCN_INPUT_BUFFER.StartingVcn`. the `RETRIEVAL_POINTERS_BUFFER.StartingVcn` <= `STARTING_VCN_INPUT_BUFFER.StartingVcn`. and when `STARTING_VCN_INPUT_BUFFER.StartingVcn == 0` of course and `RETRIEVAL_POINTERS_BUFFER.StartingVcn == 0`

Comment: Not sure I got all of that, but I'm interested in the startingvcn = 0 case, so as long as that works, I'm happy.

Comment: of course in case `STARTING_VCN_INPUT_BUFFER.StartingVcn == 0` the `RETRIEVAL_POINTERS_BUFFER.StartingVcn == 0` - also will be 0 - can not be another value